# How to cartographically represent active faults, without using geological symbols

Tags: symbology, cartography

I would like to ask how to cartographically represent active faults, without using geological symbols. I don't want to make a geological map, that's why I don't use that kind of symbology. I don't have the ages of faults, but I do have the type. I saw how the United States Geological Survey (USGS) made similar maps, but they used "age" instead of "type" (of faults).

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you don't want to use geological symbols, then the sky's the limit.  Faults are typically represented by different colour lines.  Just choose different colours based on type.  Do you have an example of what you'd like it to look like?  A google search on ["active faults map"](https://www.google.com.au/search?espv=2&biw=1920&bih=1115&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=active+faults+map&oq=active+faults+map&gs_l=img.3...0.0.0.25286.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.img..0.0.0.l_kn8y4E2r8) yields a lot of different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active faults are generally represented with a continuous line. You could use different colours for the active and inactive faults but the same linetype (e.g. continuous red line for active and continuous black line for inactive). Also fault extensions or possible faults are represented with a dashed line. In the case that you want to create a greyscale map and not a coloured one, using different linetypes is the only way. If you want to play by the book, you should use a linetype that symbolizes the hanging and foot walls of the fault (but since you do not need the geological information you can stick with the aforementioned).

Regarding the USGS symbology you mention, you could also group the faults by ages, since the inactive faults are characterised so based on the geological period they gave their last movement. If I remember correctly a fault is regarded as inactive if it was last active during the Neogene System.

Comment: thank you for your reply! i wanna make a coloured one and not a greyscale map.. one last question, what kind of colors you suggest me to put for the faults? i was thinking red (red shade)..

Comment: I would use mars or crimson red for the active faults and maybe amber for the inactive faults. It doesn't really matter. Just make sure to put a legend on your map that explains everything.